# How to map jpa Entities when I have shared column (but not only) in the primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have to maintain/improve a legacy system with many cases like this. 
The Example

```
create table COMPANY(
    COMP_ID_COMPANY NUMBER(10),
    COMP_NAME VARCHAR(32),
    /*... MANY FIELDS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (COMP_ID_COMPANY)
);

create table BUSINESS_UNIT(
    BUZZ_ID_COMPANY NUMBER(10),
    BUZZ_ID_BUZZUNIT NUMBER(10),
    /*... MANY FIELDS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (BUZZ_ID_COMPANY, BUZZ_ID_BUZZUNIT),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BUZZ_COMP FOREIGN KEY (BUZZ_ID_COMPANY) REFERENCES COMPANY (COMP_ID_COMPANY)
)

create table BRANCH(
    BRAN_ID_COMPANY NUMBER(10),
    BRAN_ID_BRANCH NUMBER(10),
    BRAN_NAME VARCHAR(32),
    /*... MANY FIELDS*/
    BRAN_ID_BUZZUNIT NUMBER(10) nullable, /*HERE IS THE PROBLEM*/
    PRIMARY KEY (BRAN_ID_COMPANY, BRAN_ID_BRANCH),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BRAN_BUZZ FOREIGN KEY (BRAN_ID_COMPANY, BRAN_ID_BUZZUNIT) REFERENCES BUSINESS_UNIT (BUZZ_ID_COMPANY, BUZZ_ID_BUZZUNIT) /*HERE IS THE PROBLEM*/
);
```

The mapping of the two first units are simple, I Have to create a class for the COMPANY PK and annotate with @EmbeddedId and @Embeddable.
But, on the Branch class i have this problem

```
@Embeddable
class BranchPk{
    @Column(name="BRAN_ID_COMPANY")
    private Long branIdCompany;
    @Column(name="BRAN_ID_BRANCH")
    private Long branIdBranch;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="BRANCH"
class Branch {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BranchPk pk;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="BRAN_ID_COMPANY", insertable=false, updatable=false), //I cannot keep this field insertable or updatable because makes part of the primary key
        @JoinColumn(name="BRAN_ID_BUZZUNIT"), //JPA doesn't allow me to mix the insertable/updatable fields with noninsertable/nonupdatable ones
    })
    private BusinessUnit businessUnit;
}
```

The question is: How can i map this class allowing businessUnit property to be null and not erasing branIdCompany from PK?
I wish to solve this using only JPA, but use hibernate specificities is not a problem for me.

Comment: While i Can't reach a solution for this. I've been mapping the columns individualy and setting them one by one, and the relationship I'm mapping as readonly (insertable=false, updatable=false). One think that i'm not tested yet is change the setter method to set the individual properties that actually will do the changes on database.